# jquery .html() method error [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery ajax to create element.

here's the code so far :

```
$('button[type="search"]').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('fine.search') }}",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 
        '_token' : '{{csrf_token() }}',
        'driver_id' : $('select[name="driver_id"]').val(),
        'fine_date' : $('input[name="fine_date"]').val(),
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        if(data.status == true) { 

        var result= ''; 

        $.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) { 
        result +=  $('<input/>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',}).attr({ type: 'radio', name: 'car_id'}).val(data.car_id);
        result += $('<div>' + data.plate_no + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',});
        result += $('<div>' + data.start_time + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',});
        result += $('<div>' + data.end_time + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',});
        }); 
        $('#search-result').html(result); 
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
       if(data.getCarbyDriver == null) { // if the result is null
            $('#noData').show();
            $(".row-bot, #search-result").hide(); // show the div..
        } 
    }
});  
});
```

everytime im running ajax using button search, it throw this error : [object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]

but the data returned properly on inspect element like this :

```
{start_time: "2016-11-12 08:00:00", end_time: "2016-11-12 18:00:00", car_id: 1, plate_no: "IT69164NO",…}
```

Comment: where you get his error?

Comment: everytime I'm running the ajax.

Comment: That is not an “error”, but the result of trying to use an array or object in a string context.

Answer (score 4):

Here you re trying to create elements using jQuery `$(something)` will return a jQuery Object, which you are trying to append to `result`. This will result in getting the string `[object Object]`.

The solution is to push the newly created elements to a `results` array and use `$('#search-result').append(result);`

Use `$('#search-result').empty().append(result);` if you want to clear existing items and add new ones. This will help you avoid duplicates.

Here is the modified success handler:

```
   var result= []; 

    $.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) { 
        result.push(
            $('<input/>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',}).attr({ type: 'radio', name: 'car_id'}).val(data.car_id),
            $('<div>' + data.plate_no + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',}),
            $('<div>' + data.start_time + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',}),
            $('<div>' + data.end_time + '</div>', {"class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',})
        );
    }); 

    $('#search-result').empty().append(result);
```

Comment: I've tried append, but I dont want the result being duplicate.

Comment: well, you can use `$('#search-result').empty().append(result);` if you want to avoid duplicates.

Comment: if you dont want to duplicate, use .html() instead.

Comment: well thanks mate. a bit issue, when data is null it show div with 'no data' . but when i find to another date which that date have data. the div doesn't hide. any idea ?

Comment: @AndrewVanusi: that depends on your application logic. I guess you have to handle the case when data is empty. Maybe show a different div if `results.length` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating an object and treating it like a String. Instead, append the object straight to the container (`"#search-result"`). You can try something like that:

```
$.each(data.getCarbyDriver, function(i, data) {
    var searchResult = $('#search-result');
    $('<input/>', {
            "class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',
            radio: 'car_id',
            value: data.car_id
        }).appendTo(searchResult);
    $('<div/>', {
            "class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',
            text: data.plate_no
        }).appendTo(searchResult);
    $('<div/>', {
            "class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',
            text: data.start_time
        }).appendTo(searchResult);
    $('<div/>', {
            "class": 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3',
            text: data.end_time
        }).appendTo(searchResult);
}
```